# AJAX request alerts JSP code

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

In an HTML file, I wrote the following AJAX request:

```
var server_query = new XMLHttpRequest();
server_query.open("GET", "try.jsp?name=Adam", false);
server_query.send();
a = server_query.responseText;
alert(a);
```

And in my JSP file I wrote the following:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*" %>

<%
    PrintWriter reply = response.getWriter();
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    reply.print(name);  
%>
```

Now when I run my file in the browser, instead of showing the name, the alert shows the entire JSP code. I'm not able to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: `responseText` should assigned to `a` on successfull response from server side, but you are not doing this.

Comment: @SumanBogati — There *is* a successful response from server side, and it is being assigned, it just doesn't contain the data the OP expects.

Comment: I think you are write `shows entire jsp code` does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have either not configured your HTTP server to process that file for JSP directives, or you aren't using an HTTP server that supports JSP at all.

Comment: Oh, okay. I am sorry, i thought it was the code. sorry.